# Rename app.config

Tags: c#, monodevelop, xbuild

I have two projects, that use the same code in the same location, but use different dependencies and app.config files, and both projects compile to the same exe name.

Currently, I have a PreBuild script configured, that copies the correct file from `project_a.config` or `project_b.config` to `app.config`.

Unfortunately, XBuild does not execute the PreBuild scripts when running from command line, so I have to do the copying before building.

Is there a way to use another file as app.config?

**EDIT:**
Note, that this is only running on Linux.

The entry in my csproj file:

```
 <Command type="BeforeBuild" 
   command="cp -f MonoMultiJack.Linux.config app.config"
   workingdir="${ProjectDir}" />
```

And this is my build script:

```
#!/bin/bash
XBUILD=xbuild
SOLUTION=MonoMultiJack.Lnx.sln
# do some other stuff
${XBUILD} ${SOLUTION} /p:Configuration=Release /t:Clean
${XBUILD} ${SOLUTION} /p:Configuration=Release
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508020/give-app-config-another-name-after-build

Comment: where do you get the assumption "Unfortunately, XBuild does not execute the PreBuild scripts when running from command line, so I have to do the copying before building." from?

Comment: @knocte: I have tested it: XBuild does not copy the file to app.config before running with `${XBUILD} ${SOLUTION} /p:Configuration=Release`. This is also referenced on the web, e.g. http://wiki.directproject.org/share/view/25772231

Comment: The example that appears on that page is a command which is not cross-platform, so the reason is not that `xbuild doesn't run PreBuild scripts` it is that you must make sure that those scripts are cross platform! otherwise they only work in one platform

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, XBuild does not execute the PreBuild scripts when
>   running from command line, so I have to do the copying before
>   building.

This assumption of yours is wrong. PreBuild events work fine in xbuild, just as they do in MSBuild. What doesn't work is a script that is not cross-platform, such as using `cmd.exe` or the `copy` command (in Unix it's called `cp`), which only exist in Windows.

To prevent this problem, you need to use MSBuild conditions with xbuild, such as the ones explained [here](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/porting_msbuild_projects_to_xbuild/#prepostbuildevents.).